# Error with NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have created a uitext view as below:

```
in the h.file
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strDescription;

in the m file

@synthesize strDescription;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   GRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 369);
    tblAddEquipment = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tblAddEquipment.delegate = self;
    tblAddEquipment.dataSource = self;
    //avoid reusable
    [self.view addSubview:tblAddEquipment];
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    //self.tblAddEquipment.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [tblAddEquipment release];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    strDescription = textView.text;
    NSLog(@"strDescription textView#####################--> %@", strDescription);
    [tblAddEquipment reloadData];
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      NSLog(@"str Description in tableview--> %@", strDescription);

      UITextView *txtDescription;

                   cellRectangle = CGRectMake( 175, 1, 120, 40 );               
                    txtDescription = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: cellRectangle];
                    txtDescription.font = font;
                    //txtDescription.scrollEnabled = YES;
                    txtDescription.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    txtDescription.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtDescription];   
                    txtDescription.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
                    txtDescription.delegate = self;
                    txtDescription.tag = 10;
                    NSString *strDesc = strDescription;
                    NSLog(@"strDesc in tableview--> %@", strDesc);
                    txtDescription.text = strDesc;
                    [txtDescription release];


}
```

When I complete entering the text in the textview, `textViewDidEndEditing` method gets called.

In that, I get `textView` text input. I store it in the `strDescription` variable. I'm able to print it over there. It shows the text assigned to it correctly.

But when the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called, I tried to print the `strDescription` variable, but it crashes and shows `exc_bad_access`.

I have been facing this issue for a long time. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me up.

Comment: I think you should be using "self.strDescription"

Comment: Is 'cellForRowAtIndexPath` crashing on the first line (NSLog), or is strDescription being written successfully and then the method is crashing later?

Comment: No in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method , i cant get the strDescription ( NSlog ).any helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have retained `strDescription` but in your code it seems me, you are not using that,
because the below statement will not increment the retain count,

```
strDescription = textView.text;
```

Use below instead

```
self.strDescription = textView.text;
```

Use below code

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    self.strDescription = textView.text;
    NSLog(@"strDescription textView#####################--> %@", strDescription);
    [tblAddEquipment reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and can you pls explain me what is the diffrence between them and why it is crashing

Comment: @barbgal : As i mentioned , using with "self" invoke setter function for that variable and by default setter function for all synthesize variables have code to increase the retain count. you apps crashed because you are trying to a over released object.

Answer (score 0):

First, this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

need to return UITableViewCell object i think…

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line in `textViewDidFinishEditing` to this:

```
strDescription = [NSString stringWithFormatString:@"%@", textView.text];
```

Comment: @Jhaliya: no, I read the question very carefully, I just didn't know what the problem was. I knew that synthesized properties did a `retain` internally, but I did not realize that this only happens if the property is prefaced with `self`. Thank you very much for the information.